# Passing arguments to angularjs filters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

Is it possible to pass an argument to the filter function so you can filter by any name?

Something like

```
$scope.weDontLike = function(item, name) {
    console.log(arguments);
    return item.name != name;
};
```

Answer (score 229, accepted):

Actually there is another (maybe better solution) where you can use the angular's native 'filter' filter and still pass arguments to your custom filter.

Consider the following code:

```
<div ng-repeat="group in groups">
    <li ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:weDontLike(group.enemy.name)">
        <span>{{friend.name}}</span>
    <li>
</div>
```

To make this work you just define your filter as the following:

```
$scope.weDontLike = function(name) {
    return function(friend) {
        return friend.name != name;
    }
}
```

As you can see here, weDontLike actually returns another function which has your parameter in its scope as well as the original item coming from the filter.

It took me 2 days to realise you can do this, haven't seen this solution anywhere yet.

Checkout [Reverse polarity of an angular.js filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13464809/reverse-polarity-of-an-angular-js-filter/17811582#17811582) to see how you can use this for other useful operations with filter.

Comment: In case your filter needs multiple arguments, see [How do I call an Angular.js filter with multiple arguments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227325/how-do-i-call-an-angular-js-filter-with-multiple-arguments)

Comment: This method also solved a weird issue where inside ng-repeat I couldnt pass my own parameters to my filter. No matter what I did they kept coming back as the index and the overall collection. By doing this return method I was able to pass my parameters and still load the original element, great fix!

Comment: @DennisSmolek I have one doubt I am struck in this point from long time. How are getting access to `friend` in the filter function `$scope.weDontLike`. In my case when I try I get the error message saying that 'angular.js:12520 ReferenceError: friend is not defined'

Answer (score 76):

From what I understand you can't pass an arguments to a filter function (when using the 'filter' filter). What you would have to do is to write a custom filter, sth like this:

```
.filter('weDontLike', function(){

return function(items, name){

    var arrayToReturn = [];        
    for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
        if (items[i].name != name) {
            arrayToReturn.push(items[i]);
        }
    }

    return arrayToReturn;
};
```

Here is the working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pkozlowski_opensource/myr4a/1/

The other simple alternative, without writing custom filters is to store a name to filter out in a scope and then write:

```
$scope.weDontLike = function(item) {
  return item.name != $scope.name;
};
```

Comment: Thats prefect thanks!  Storing the name in the scope won't work so well as I have three lists from the same data on the same page im filtering with different states (or names).

Comment: any to set 'Adam' (referring to your JSFiddle) dynamically? it seems impossible (and I guess that's on purpose) to combine ngModel and a custom filter in Angular...

Comment: Is it possible to reorder the parameters of a filter? For example pass the item to the second parameter of a filter?

Comment: It is worth noting that in this example the markup is {{ items | weDontLike:'thenameyoudontlike' }} ... right now you have to go to the fiddle to get that. Also worth noting that you can pass multiple params to your custom filter {{ items |  weDontLike:'thename':['I am', 'an array']:'and so on' }} you would just add more arguments to your custom filter to have access to them.

Answer (score 62):

Actually you can pass a parameter ( http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter ) and don't need a custom function just for this. If you rewrite your HTML as below it'll work:

```
<div ng:app>
 <div ng-controller="HelloCntl">
 <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:{name:'!Adam'}">
        <span>{{friend.name}}</span>
        <span>{{friend.phone}}</span>
    </li>
 </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZfGx4/59/

Comment: Yes. Side note - if somebody's name is '!Adam', you get him like {name:'!!Adam'}.

Comment: You can also pass arrays here too like this `filter:['Adam', 'john']`

Comment: jsfiddle link is broken.

Comment: !Adam is the worst name ever

Comment: Not-Not-Adam is obviously worse.

Answer (score 31):

You can simply do like this 
In Template

```
<span ng-cloak>{{amount |firstFiler:'firstArgument':'secondArgument' }}</span>
```

In filter

```
angular.module("app")
.filter("firstFiler",function(){

    console.log("filter loads");
    return function(items, firstArgument,secondArgument){
        console.log("item is ",items); // it is value upon which you have to filter
        console.log("firstArgument is ",firstArgument);
        console.log("secondArgument ",secondArgument);

        return "hello";
    }
    });
```

Comment: This is the best answer. It works with dynamic objects. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Extending on [pkozlowski.opensource's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11753593/3568919) and using javascript `array's` builtin filter method a prettified solution could be this:

```
.filter('weDontLike', function(){
    return function(items, name){
        return items.filter(function(item) {
            return item.name != name;
        });
    };
});
```

Here's the jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/nasiftanjim/0qLexbdg/2/).

More on Array filter [here](http://eloquentjavascript.net/05_higher_order.html#h_1BJbwiI0gI).

Answer (score 1):

You can pass multiple arguments to angular filter !

Defining my angular app and and an app level variable -

```
var app = angular.module('filterApp',[]);
app.value('test_obj', {'TEST' : 'test be check se'});
```

Your Filter will be like :-

```
app.filter('testFilter', [ 'test_obj', function(test_obj) {
    function test_filter_function(key, dynamic_data) {
      if(dynamic_data){
        var temp = test_obj[key]; 
        for(var property in dynamic_data){
            temp = temp.replace(property, dynamic_data[property]);
        }
        return temp;
      }
      else{
        return test_obj[key] || key;
      }

    }
    test_filter_function.$stateful = true;
    return test_filter_function;
  }]);
```

And from HTML you will send data like :-

```
<span ng-bind="'TEST' | testFilter: { 'be': val, 'se': value2 }"></span>
```

Here I am sending a JSON object to the filter.
You can also send any kind of data like string or number.

also you can pass dynamic number of arguments to filter , 
in that case you have to use ***arguments*** to get those arguments.

For a working demo go here -   [passing multiple arguments to angular filter](https://jsfiddle.net/darkarcherroy/ahzgs6vu/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use  `| filter:yourFunction:arg`

```
<div ng-repeat="group in groups | filter:weDontLike:group">...</div>
```

And in js

```
$scope.weDontLike = function(group) {
//here your condition/criteria
return !!group 
}
```