# How to use parameters within the filter in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to use parameter in filter, when I iterate some arrays with ng-repeat

Example:

HTML-Part:

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users | filter:isActive">
```

JavaScript-part:

```
$scope.isActive = function(user) {
    return user.active === "1";
};
```

But I want to be able to use filter like

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users | filter:isStatus('4')">
```

But its not working. How can I do something like that?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

**UPDATE:** I guess I didn't really look at the documentation well enough but you can definitely use the [filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter) filter with this syntax (see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4PYZa/2/)) to filter by a property on the objects:

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users | filter:{status:4}">
```

---

Here's my original answer in case it helps someone:

Using the [filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter) filter you won't be able to pass in a parameter but there are at least two things you can do.

**1) Set the data you want to filter by in a scope variable and reference that in your filter function like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4PYZa/1/).**

JavaScript:

```
$scope.status = 1;
$scope.users = [{name: 'first user', status: 1},
                {name: 'second user', status: 2},
                {name: 'third user', status: 3}];

$scope.isStatus = function(user){
    return (user.status == $scope.status);
};
```

Html:

```
<li ng-repeat="user in users | filter:isStatus">
```

OR

**2) Create a new filter that takes in a parameter like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZMkQY/2/).**

JavaScript:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.filter('isStatus', function() {
  return function(input, status) {
    var out = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
          if(input[i].status == status)
              out.push(input[i]);
      }      
    return out;
  };
});
```

Html:

```
<li ng-repeat="user in users | isStatus:3">
```

Note this filter assumes there is a `status` property in the objects in the array which might make it less reusable but this is just an example. You can read [this](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.templates.filters.creating_filters) for more info on creating filters.

Comment: @mcranston18 the 3 fiddles I linked to work for me in the latest version of Chrome. Where is it breaking for you?

Comment: For 2), it might be useful to know that [you can pass multiple arguments to your custom filters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227325), even from templates.

Comment: What if I want to filter on "name" and "status" both. User can enter name OR status in text box and I want it to filter. Is there any way, Ex:filter:{status:4, name:Mark}"

Comment: @Gloopy can you please help me on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72108427/how-do-i-filter-name-in-ng-repeat-angularjs

Answer (score 52):

This question is almost identical to [Passing arguments to angularjs filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753321/passing-arguments-to-angularjs-filters/), to which I already gave an answer. But I'm gonna post one more answer here just so that people see it.

Actually there is another (maybe better solution) where you can use the angular's native 'filter' filter and still pass arguments to your custom filter.

Consider the following code:

```
    <li ng-repeat="user in users | filter:byStatusId(3)">
        <span>{{user.name}}</span>
    <li>
```

To make this work you just define your filter as the following:

```
$scope.byStatusId = function(statusId) {
    return function(user) {
        return user.status.id == statusId;
    }
}
```

This approach is more versatile because you can do comparisons on values that are nested deep inside the object.

Checkout [Reverse polarity of an angular.js filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13464809/reverse-polarity-of-an-angular-js-filter/17811582#17811582) to see how you can use this for other useful operations with filter.

Comment: For some strange reason this just doesn't work for me. I have an `ng-repeat="a in array | filter: myFilterFunc">` in the view. In the controller I have `$scope.myFilterFunc = function() {..}`... it just doesn't work.

Comment: Please take a closer look at my answer, your filter has to return a function as in `$scope.myFilterFunc = function() { return function(item) { // actual filter code goes here } }` AND you must call filter as a function, such as `filter:myFilterFunc()`

Comment: @DenisPshenov what if I wanted to include `a` and another value? `<li ng-repeat="status in statuses | filter:currentStatus(status, scopevar.status)" `??? <--This doesn't work

Comment: @Garry, You would then need to request for that other value in your filter like `$scope.currentStatus = function(status, otherValue) { ... }`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @DenisPshenov The problem I was having was in the visibility of `status` when using an additional variable. I took a different approach using `ng-model` and `ng-options`

Answer (score 1):

If you have created an AngularJs custom filter, you can send multiple params to your filter.Here is usage in template

```
{{ variable | myFilter:arg1:arg2...  }}
```

and if you use filter inside your controller here is how you can do that

```
angular.module('MyModule').controller('MyCtrl',function($scope, $filter){
    $filter('MyFilter')(arg1, arg2, ...);
})
```

if you need more with examples and online demo, you can use this

[AngularJs filters examples and demo](http://www.w3docs.com/snippets/angularjs/how-to-use-angularjs-filters.html)

Answer (score 0):

This may be slightly irrelevant, but if you're trying to apply multiple filters with custom functions, you should look into:
https://github.com/tak215/angular-filter-manager

Answer (score 0):

Example I have a students list as below :

```
$scope.students = [  
   { name: 'Hai', age: 25, gender: 'boy' },  
   { name: 'Hai', age: 30, gender: 'girl' },  
   { name: 'Ho', age: 25, gender: 'boy' },  
   { name: 'Hoan', age: 40, gender: 'girl' },  
   { name: 'Hieu', age: 25, gender: 'boy' }  
 ];
```

I want to filter students via gender to be boy and filter by name of them.

The first I create a function named "filterbyboy" as following:

```
$scope.filterbyboy = function (genderstr) {  
   if ((typeof $scope.search === 'undefined')||($scope.search === ''))  
     return (genderstr = "")  
   else  
    return (genderstr = "boy");  
 };
```

Explaination: if not filter name then display all students else filter by input name and gender as 'boy'

Here is full HTMLcode and demo [How to use and operator in AngularJs example](http://angularjsaz.blogspot.com/2015/10/filter-by-and-operator-in-angularjs.html)