# How do I call an Angular.js filter with multiple arguments?

Tags: angularjs

As from the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$filter), we can call a filter such as [date](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:date) like this:

```
{{ myDateInScope | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd' }}
```

Here date is a filter that takes one argument.

What is the syntax to call filters with more parameters both from templates and from JavaScript code?

Answer (score 644, accepted):

In templates, you can separate filter arguments by **colons**.

```
{{ yourExpression | yourFilter: arg1:arg2:... }}
```

From Javascript, you call it as

```
$filter('yourFilter')(yourExpression, arg1, arg2, ...)
```

There is actually an example hidden in the [orderBy](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:orderBy) filter docs.

---

**Example:**

Let's say  you make a filter that can replace things with regular expressions:

```
myApp.filter("regexReplace", function() { // register new filter

  return function(input, searchRegex, replaceRegex) { // filter arguments

    return input.replace(RegExp(searchRegex), replaceRegex); // implementation

  };
});
```

Invocation in a template to censor out all digits:

```
<p>{{ myText | regexReplace: '[0-9]':'X' }}</p>
```

Comment: In HTML Template Binding
{{ filter_expression | filter:expression:comparator }},
In JavaScript
$filter('filter')(filter_expression, expression, comparator)

Comment: @pulkitsinghal what do you mean? Show your problematic code in JSFiddle or Plunker.

Comment: Would have been nice if you just posted the filter in Javascript

Comment: @ObiOnuorah OK, just translated the Coffeescript to Javascript.

Comment: Good stuff. Why isn't this answer in the top of the list ?

Comment: @nh2 Would you be able to update your answer with the suggestion from srox00? The javascript should be `$filter('yourFilter')(yourExpression, arg1, arg2, ...)`

Comment: @Dylanthepiguy OK, fixed!

Comment: For any beginners here, it would be terrible to use an AngularJS to filter digits like this because the client could easy rig up the Javascript to not apply the filter. (This would apply to any client-side scripting language)

Answer (score 11):

i mentioned in the below where i have mentioned the custom filter also , how to call these filter which is having two parameters

```
countryApp.filter('reverse', function() {
    return function(input, uppercase) {
        var out = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            out = input.charAt(i) + out;
        }
        if (uppercase) {
            out = out.toUpperCase();
        }
        return out;
    }
});
```

and from the html using the template we can call that filter like below

```
<h1>{{inputString| reverse:true }}</h1>
```

here if you see , the first parameter is  inputString  and second parameter is true which is combined with "reverse'  using the :  symbol

Answer (score 4):

If you want to call your filter inside ng-options the code will be as follows:

```
ng-options="productSize as ( productSize | sizeWithPrice: product )  for productSize in productSizes track by productSize.id"
```

where the filter is sizeWithPriceFilter and it has two parameters product and productSize

Answer (score 1):

like this:

```
var items = $filter('filter')(array, {Column1:false,Column2:'Pending'});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need two or more dealings with the filter, is possible to chain them:

```
{{ value | decimalRound: 2 | currencySimbol: 'U$' }} 
// 11.1111 becomes U$ 11.11
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227325/how-do-i-call-an-angular-js-filter-with-multiple-arguments

Comment: Doesn't address the question "How do I call an Angular.js filter with multiple arguments?" (rather than "How do I call multiple filters?")

Answer (score -1):

In this code, jsondata is our array and in function return we are checking the 'version' present in the jsondata.

```
var as = $filter('filter')(jsondata, function (n,jsondata){
   return n.filter.version==='V.0.3'
});

console.log("name is " + as[0].name+as[0]);
```