# AngularJS : Custom filters and ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I'm an AngularJS newbie and I'm building up a small proof-of-concept car hire listings app that pulls in some JSON and renders out various bits of that data via an ng-repeat, with a couple of filters:

```
   <article data-ng-repeat="result in results | filter:search" class="result">
        <header><h3>{{result.carType.name}}, {{result.carDetails.doors}} door, &pound;{{result.price.value}} - {{ result.company.name }}</h3></header>
            <ul class="result-features">
                <li>{{result.carDetails.hireDuration}} day hire</li>
                <li data-ng-show="result.carDetails.airCon">Air conditioning</li>
                <li data-ng-show="result.carDetails.unlimitedMileage">Unlimited Mileage</li>
                <li data-ng-show="result.carDetails.theftProtection">Theft Protection</li>
            </ul>
    </article>

    <h2>Filters</h2>

    <h4>Doors:</h4> 
    <select data-ng-model="search.carDetails">
        <option value="">All</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
    </select>

    <h4>Provider:</h4>
    Atlas Choice <input type="checkbox"  data-ng-model="search.company" ng-true-value="Atlas Choice" ng-false-value="" value="Atlas Choice" /><br>
    Holiday Autos <input type="checkbox"  data-ng-model="search.company" ng-true-value="Holiday Autos" ng-false-value="" value="Holiday Autos" /><br>
    Avis <input type="checkbox"  data-ng-model="search.company" ng-true-value="Avis" ng-false-value="" value="Avis" /><br>
```

Now I want to create a custom filter in my controller, that can iterate over the items in my ng-repeat and return only the items that meet certain criteria - for example, I might create an array of values based on which 'provider' checkboxes are checked, then evaluate each ng-repeat item against that. I just can't work out how I'd do that though, in terms of the syntax - can anyone help?

Here's my Plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/lNJNYagMC2rszbSOF95k?p=preview

Answer (score 168, accepted):

If you want to run some custom filter logic you can create a function which takes the array element as an argument and returns `true` or `false` based on whether it should be in the search results. Then pass it to the `filter` instruction just like you do with the `search` object, for example:

**JS:**

```
$scope.filterFn = function(car)
{
    // Do some tests

    if(car.carDetails.doors > 2)
    {
        return true; // this will be listed in the results
    }

    return false; // otherwise it won't be within the results
};
```

**HTML:**

```
...
<article data-ng-repeat="result in results | filter:search | filter:filterFn" class="result">
...
```

As you can see you can chain many filters together, so adding your custom filter function doesn't force you to remove the previous filter using the `search` object (they will work together seamlessly).

Comment: Very interesting! The filter can be simplified to `return car.carDetails.doors > 2;` though.

Comment: Of course it can. I've decided for a more verbose version, however, to make it more clear as a learning example.

Comment: In case you need more sophisticated filters, you can also [pass your filters more than one argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227325/how-do-i-call-an-angular-js-filter-with-multiple-arguments).

Comment: @mirrimx i didnt get when this function will be called ?

Comment: @nh2 is there any way to pass more then one argument into a filter defined as a controller function, rather then a filter defined as en explicit $filter?

Comment: @AbrahamP Unfortunately I don't know that.

Comment: Is there a way to match one filter or another.  IE if you had 2 custom filters could you match customFilter1 OR customFilter2?

Comment: I like `return (car.carDetails.doors > 2);`

Comment: When you are working directly with $scope then you can access the search criteria directly through $scope. What is the solution when you are working with the "as vm" option ? in that case 'this' is not the controller.

Comment: Heck, if we're flexing, function could be inlined as data-ng-repeat="r in results | filter:search | filter:function(r){return r.carDetails.doors>2;}" or smth. But if you want to get called again for future contracts, prefer the readable answer above. There's zero performance gain.

Answer (score 34):

If you still want a custom filter you can pass in the search model to the filter:

```
<article data-ng-repeat="result in results | cartypefilter:search" class="result">
```

Where definition for the cartypefilter can look like this:

```
app.filter('cartypefilter', function() {
  return function(items, search) {
    if (!search) {
      return items;
    }

    var carType = search.carType;
    if (!carType || '' === carType) {
      return items;
    }

    return items.filter(function(element, index, array) {
      return element.carType.name === search.carType;
    });

  };
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/kBcUIayO8tQsTTjTA2vO?p=preview

Comment: can you give more than one parameter to a custom filter?

Answer (score 6):

You can call more of 1 function filters in the same ng-repeat filter

```
<article data-ng-repeat="result in results | filter:search() | filter:filterFn()" class="result">
```

Comment: possible to OR filters instead of AND?

Comment: mmm... i think the best option is a function to do that, here is an example (not work)

http://plnkr.co/edit/PNwyDKXk9RQcur8Tpp8w?p=preview

best

Answer (score 2):

One of the easiest ways to fix this is to use the `$` which is the search all.

Here is a plunker that shows it working. I have changed the checkboxes to radio ( because I thought they should be complementary )..

http://plnkr.co/edit/dHzvm6hR5P8G4wPuTxoi?p=preview

If you want a very specific way of doing this ( instead of doing a generic search ) you need work with functions in the search.

The documentation is here

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter