# limitTo not working in ng-repeat in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working out some code for some application.
I want to limit the messages in the chat

```
this.limitM = -10;
$scope.msgsCount = //contains the number of messages


<button ng-if="msgsCount > -main.limitM" 
ng-click="main.limitM=-10+main.limitM">Load More</button>

<li class="singleMessage clearfix" 
    ng-repeat="msg in chat.msgs | limitTo:main.limitM" 
    ng-class="::{myMessage: msg.senderName != chat.name}">

<img class="profileImage" alt="::{{chat.name}}" width="40px">
    <p ng-bind-html="parseMsg(msg)"></p>
</li>
```

This is not limiting the messages, all the messages appear.
Can anyone help ?

Comment: hi check this post looks some filter atribute needs to be added ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19601028/using-ng-repeat-and-limitto-to-limit-the-number-of-visible-items-displayed

Comment: no adding filter is not working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you have to define all necessary variables to make it work. 
Example of your controller:

```
$scope.limit = 3;
$scope.expand = function(limit) { 
  $scope.limit += limit;
}
$scope.chat = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven'];
```

And view:

```
 <button ng-if="chat.length > limit" ng-click="expand(limit)">Load More</button>
 <li ng-repeat="msg in chat | limitTo : limit" >{{ msg }}</li>
```

Here is a simple **[plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/oijlVkgkSxg7Cq7LU2VM?p=preview)**, that does what you need.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why your list is not limited is because `main.limitM` is undefined.

I believe you are calling `this.limitM = -10;` inside the controller.  Views cannot see the limitM variable. They only have access to variables defined on $scope.

Change `this.limitM` to `$scope.limitM` and `main.limitM` to `limitM`

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try this:

```
$scope.limitM = 10; // This is your scope's limit

<button ng-click="limitM = 20">Load More</button>

<li ng-repeat="msg in chat.msgs | limitTo: limitM">{{msg}}</li>
```

It should work, according to the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo).

**EDIT**

Check this [jsfiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/oh094b4t/) to see a working example of what you try to accomplish.

Comment: I converted this.limitM to $scope.limitM and made the change, but still doesn't limit

Comment: Also if i just remove limitTo: limitM and change to a number -10.It stil doesnt limit

Comment: @HemankSabrawal I edited my post to add a fiddle with the working solution