# How do I limit the number of objects I want to show in my ng-repeat,

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

This it my objects with arrays:

```
01-543BY: Array[1]
03-45BD23: Array[1]
03-67BS50: Array[1]
06-78FR90: Array[1]
07-467BY3: Array[1]
09-23DF76: Array[1]
```

Currently I have six, but I only want to show 4.
This is my ng-repeat:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, item) in product.productListByCategoriesShow ">
```

I tried `<div ng-repeat="(key, item) in product.productListByCategoriesShow |limitTo: 4 ">`
But it seems not working. Any suggestions? Thx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using ng-repeat and limitTo to limit the number of visible items displayed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19601028/using-ng-repeat-and-limitto-to-limit-the-number-of-visible-items-displayed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'vs solved my problem.

limitTo, does not work for objects, only arrays and string, so what I id was to place my object into sets of arrays.

So instead of this:

```
01-543BY: Array[1]
03-45BD23: Array[1]
03-67BS50: Array[1]
06-78FR90: Array[1]
07-467BY3: Array[1]
09-23DF76: Array[1]
```

I did this: `[Array[1], Array[1], Array[1], Array[1], Array[1], Array[1]]`
using the angular.foreach and .push(only works for arrays) it to an array.

So now my   myarray | limitTo:4 works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use this helper filter for a situation like this:

```
module.filter('keys', [
    function () {
        return function (object) {
            return Object.keys(object);
        }
    }
]);
```

And then use it like:

```
<div ng-repeat="key in product.productListByCategoriesShow | keys | limitTo: 4" 
     ng-init="item = product.productListByCategoriesShow[key]">
     ...
</div>
```

**Demo:**

http://plnkr.co/edit/5edaa8qScyhseB0B1Z9o?p=preview

I'd recommend sorting the keys using `filter` to guarantee order, as well, before calling `limitTo`.  I'm guessing that the angular team didn't make `limitTo` work on objects because the order would potentially be volatile?

Answer (score 0):

limitTo: {{size you want}} filter will help you in showing the number of element in list you want to display.
Check this doc : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo

Comment: @Tushar can you able to iterate this list using ng-repeat? because i fine the  data structure for it is not a array.

Comment: Read the last sentence in the question _I tried <div ng-repeat="(key, item) in product.productListByCategoriesShow |limitTo: 4 "> But it seems not working. Any suggestions? Thx_

Comment: @Tushar Yeah i have read it what i want know before getting to any solution are you able to iterate it without using limitTo : 4 . all 6 are getting displayed when you use ng-repeat on them ?

Comment: @Tushar, Im not able to use limitTo for objects, only arrays and string. Currently my data are all objects, so what i did was put them inside an array...which then lets me use limitTo. That is my solution, thx for the help tho

Answer (score 0):

You mention that you've tried

`<div ng-repeat="(key, item) in product.productListByCategoriesShow | limitTo: 4 ">`

My concern would be that `product.productListByCategoriesShow` is the array you want to apply the filter to, but angular might be trying to apply the filter to your entire 'in' statement. Have you tried:

`<div ng-repeat="(key, item) in (product.productListByCategoriesShow | limitTo: 4)">`

Comment: yea i have tried. Im not too sure if limitTo works for objects, ive only seen examples of arrays and strings so far....

Answer (score 0):

Not best solution:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, item) in product.productListByCategoriesShow" ng-if="$index < 4"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not limit the array in the controller?

```
$scope.product.productListByCategoriesShow.length = 4
```

Comment: you gave me an idea, but i dont think the syntax will be that simple? Ill try using $filter('limitTo')

Comment: Please consider adding some more explanation to this as it currently reads more as a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to track according to key you should use like this;

```
<div ng-repeat="item in product.productListByCategoriesShow |limitTo: 4 track by $key ">
```