# Unable to show filtered item after using limitTo along with ng-show and ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of famous `places`, each place contains a `tour` array with 20 elements 20 is the number of tours under each famous places. e.g. 'Egypt' contains 20 tours in its attractive locations. But problem is some tours do not contain any hotels, but some tours have hotels. Here is my code.

```
<div ng-repeat="tour in place.tours | limitTo:3" ng-show="tour.hotels.length != 0">
  <li>
    <a ng-repeat="hName in tour.hotels"> {{hName.name}}
    </a>
  </li>
 </div>
```

in 1st `ng-repeat` i have shown only the **tour** containing hotel(number of hotel is 1) using `ng-show` . in the 2nd `ng-repeat` i have displayed hotel names from the `hotels` array.

*Ultimately, i have extracted all hotel names from the tours that contain hotel using two* `ng-repeat`.

Everything is working fine, but now i want to show only first 3 hotel names from the hotel-list which i got from 2nd `ng-repeat`.  But adding  `limitTo:3` in the 1st `ng-repeat` is not showing 1st 3 hotel name, because 1st 3 elements are already hidden as there are no hotel, but there **indexes** remains ! .

i found this similar topic ,but it was unable to help [Using ng-repeat and limitTo to limit the number of visible items displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19601028/using-ng-repeat-and-limitto-to-limit-the-number-of-visible-items-displayed)

How can I show only 1st 3 hotel name from the filtered hotel list? or What i am doing wrong?

Comment: not sure if i got you're problem but try changing the `ng-show` to `ng-if` so the first 3 elements won't be rendered.
If that's not the case please share your data and clarify what you are trying to achieve

Comment: You need to use a filter https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a filter `tour in tours | filter: { hotels: []} | limitTo:3`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-filter-filter-production</title>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="">
  <div ng-init="tours = [
    {name:'A',    hotels : [ {name:'AA'},{name:'AB' }] ,    },
    {name:'B',    hotels : [ {name:'AA'},{name:'AB' }] ,    },
    {name:'D',    hotels : [ {name:'AA'}] },
    {name:'E',    hotels : [ {name:'AA'},{name:'AB' }] ,    },
    {name:'F',    hotels : [ {name:'AA'},{name:'AB' }] ,    },
    {name:'G',    hotels : [ {name:'AA'},{name:'AB' }] ,    },
    {name:'NONEA',       },
    {name:'NONEB',       }
    ]
                         "></div>
    <div ng-repeat="tour in tours | filter: { hotels: []}">
    Tour name : {{tour.name}} {{tour.hotels.length}} <br>
    <div ng-repeat="hotel in tour.hotels">
      Hotel Name : {{hotel.name}}
      <br/>
    </div>
    <br>
  </div>
</html>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/CoIdSUwVoCoY32sOnO2C?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use custom filter first and then limit.

JS

```
  $scope.filterFn = function(tour)
    {
        // Do some tests

        if(tour.hotels.length > 0)
        {
            return true; // this will be listed in the results
        }

        return false; // otherwise it won't be within the results
    };
```

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="tour in place.tours | filter:filterFn | limitTo:3">
```

Comment: Thanks @nitz i have used filer now

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'm understanding your problem correctly, but if you're trying to get the first 3 hotels for EACH tour, then you should be placing the limitTo filter in the 2nd ng-repeat.

Comment: I tried. It will not work. For now I have just 1 hotel in each tour. if i had more hotel in a single tour, 2nd ng-repeat's "limit" will limit that number.