# AngularJS : Custom Filter function not triggering

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller

```
app.controller('cartCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.$on('updateCart', function(event, cart) {
        $scope.cart = cart;
    });

    $scope.myFilter = function(item) {
        console.log(item);
    };
});
```

The view which is loaded by routes :

```
<div class="shopping-row" data-ng-repeat="item in cart.items | filter:myFilter">
<div>
```

Now the problem is that myFilter is not triggred. If I call `filter:myFilter()` it gets triggered but value isn't passed.

I fail to see why this isn't working. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is `cart.items` has be an array for the filter function to be called, if it is a object it simply ignores it. ng-repeat would still display the object.

Answer (score 0):

What if you use

> filter:myFilter(item)

Comment: I am not getting item object.

Comment: That's because you didn't define a filter but a function to be called as a filter. Please check the official documentation on writing filters : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Answer (score 0):

Error is there because you are trying to create a custom filter but you are doing it wrong.

This is how you create it.

```
angular.module('phonecatFilters', []).filter('checkmark', function() {
  return function(input) {
    return input ? '\u2713' : '\u2718';
  };
});
```

This is how you use it.

```
<dd>{{phone.connectivity.infrared | checkmark}}</dd>
```

References: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09

Comment: You don't have to "ALWAYS" create a separate filter.

Comment: See the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16563018/custom-filters-and-ng-repeat-in-angularjs

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that approach and neither should anyone. I would say keep your functionality separate and reusable.

Comment: Creating a separate filter each time you want check a specific item makes absolutely no sense.