# How to pass multiple parameter in angular filter function, not custom filter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I tried hard and visit lot of similar question like this but still unable to solve this issue.

I want to pass extra parameter in angular filter function. I found solution as below but it's not working. I am getting undefined for object which I have used in `ng-repeat`.

```
<li ng-repeat="user in users | filter:isStatus(user,secondParam)">{{user.name}}</li>
```

There are solution for angular custom filter as below but that also not working with angular filter function.

```
<li ng-repeat="user in users | filter:isStatus:user:secondParam">{{user.name}}</li>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4PYZa/278/) - You can see my problem here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Will try:

```
$scope.isStatus = function(secondParam, thirdParam){
      return function(user) {
           console.log(secondParam);
           console.log(thirdParam);
           return user.status == $scope.status;
     }
```

Updated version http://jsfiddle.net/4PYZa/282/

Answer (score 5):

According to your case, you can use predicate expression instead of custom filter:

```
<li ng-repeat="user in users | filter:{status: status, name: name}">{{user.name}}</li>
```

Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ovym2tpr/28/

You can use custom filter in anyway, it just performs not very well especially under nested `ng-repeat`

Answer (score 1):

[How do I call an Angular.js filter with multiple arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227325/how-do-i-call-an-angular-js-filter-with-multiple-arguments)

[AngularJS : Custom filters and ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16563018/custom-filters-and-ng-repeat-in-angularjs)

```
 myApp.filter("isStatus ", function() { // register new filter
     return function(user, secondParam, thirdParam) { // filter arguments

       return user.status == $scope.status; // implementation
    };
 });
```

Calling from Template

```
<li ng-repeat="user in users | isStatus:secondParam">{{user.name}}</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple , just do this

```
<li ng-repeat="user in users | filter:user | filter : secondParam)">{{user.name}}</li>
```

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted this, It's running perfectly. Do check it once.