# Why is Angularjs filtering for more than two columns using AND operation not working for me?

Tags: angularjs, json

I have a problem. Angularjs filtering for more than two columns using AND operation is not working for JSON data. Please help me out.

I want the filter to be applied based on

`"SettingsDeviated","HMRNonCompliant","MissedTherapy","NoEvent","deviceTypeVest","deviceTypeMonarch"` with check boxes next to the label.

```
{
        "id": 160,
        "email": "abc@gmail.com",
        "firstName": "abc",
        "lastName": "def",
        "isDeleted": false,
        "zipcode": 55110,
        "address": "39 Xswhss lane ",
        "city": "White Bear Lake",
        "dob": "12/21/1947",
        "gender": "Male",
        "title": null,
        "hillromId": "46399",
        "langKey": null,
        "middleName": null,
        "state": "MN",
        "mobilePhone": null,
        "primaryPhone": null,
        "createdAt": 1490167354000,
        "isActivated": true,
        "adherence": 98,
        "lastTransmissionDate": "2017-03-20",
        "lastLoggedInAt": null,
        "clinics": [],
        "hcp": null,
        "clinicMRNId": {
        },
        "clinicNamesCSV": "lmn,def Hospital",
        "hcpNamesCSV": null,
        "mrnId": null,
        "hoursOfUsage": 0.0,
        "serialNumber": null,
        "deviceType": "VEST",
        "expired": false,
        "isSettingsDeviated": false,
        "isHMRNonCompliant": true,
        "isMissedTherapy": false,
        "isNoEvent": false,
        "deviceTypeVest": true,
        "deviceTypeMonarch": false
    }
```

Comment: use [this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to format your question

Answer (score 0):

You can check this, here it has custom filter with multiple parameter  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27507114/how-to-pass-multiple-parameter-in-angular-filter-function-not-custom-filter)