# AngularJS : angular-ui-grid showing rows based on the condition

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I would like my grid to show rows that only matches a creteria. For example i want my grid to show only the rows where name is Brian.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.grid']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

  $scope.myData = [{name: "Brian", code: 50,count:20},
                 {name: "Jason", code: 43,userid:1},
                 {name: "Brian", code: 27,userid:10},
                 {name: "Devon", code: 29,userid:7},
                 {name: "Kale", code: 34,userid:2}];

  $scope.gridOptions = {
    enableSorting: true,
    data:'myData',
    columnDefs: [
      { field: 'name', displayName: 'Name'},
      {field: 'code', displayName: 'Code'},
      { field: 'userid', displayName: 'UserId'
        }
      }
    ]
  };
}]);
```

how can i accomplish that? Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the work around would be, Instead of passing `myData` do filter you criteria and then assign that filtered data to new scope variable and assign that inside your `gridOptions` data field

**Code**

```
$scope.filteredData = myData; //make filter your data manually here 

$scope.gridOptions = {
    enableSorting: true,
    data:'filteredData', //passed filtered data here.
    columnDefs: [
      { field: 'name', displayName: 'Name'},
      {field: 'code', displayName: 'Code'},
      { field: 'userid', displayName: 'UserId'
        }
      }
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `filter`. You can read about the standard angular filter [here](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_filters.asp). You can read about how to make custom filters [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16563018/custom-filters-and-ng-repeat-in-angularjs).