# angular filter using an array of more than one value

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of checkboxs:

```
 <input type="checkbox" ng-model="myFilter.filterField" ng-true-value="'value1'" ng-false-value="''"> value1<br>
 <input type="checkbox" ng-model="myFilter.filterField" ng-true-value="'value2'" ng-false-value="''"> value2<br>
```

....
....
And I want to filter the checked checkboxes fields like this:

```
x in X | filter: { 'filterField': ['value1','value2']}
```

Any solution to push into my array filterField and filter more than one value? Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered creating your own filter?

Comment: I Will need more filterFields and probably this filterFields Will Be also arrays for more than one value, how can i do that??

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16563018/angularjs-custom-filters-and-ng-repeat

Comment: mmm...not so much xd maybe i dont understand, im an angular ignorant

Comment: I'll provide an example

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use custom filters in that case

```
$scope.filterField = function(x) {
    return x.filterField == 'value1' || x.filterField == 'value2' || x.anotherField == 'value';
};


x in X | filter: filterField
```

Comment: but if i want more filter fields i need to create one function for each field ???

Comment: you can use like this x.filterField == 'value1' || x.field1 == 'value' || x.field2 == 'value1' @Charly

Answer (score 0):

From [AngularJS : Custom filters and ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16563018/angularjs-custom-filters-and-ng-repeat)

Checking multiple fields

```
// Filter, where element would be your x
$scope.filterFn = function(element)
{ 
    if(element.field === 'value1' || element.anotherField === 'value2')
    {
        return true; // this will be listed in the results
    }
    return false; // otherwise it won't be within the results
};
```

And then apply it
`x in X | filter:filterFn`

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to use one custom filter and add parameters to it. This fiddle shows how to work with a filter with multiple parameters:
http://jsfiddle.net/halirgb/Lvc0u55v/

Like this

```
myApp.filter('customFilter', function() { // Name of filter
return function(first, second,third) {
// write filter code here
  return second;// shows the last filter parameter
};});
```

And use the filter like this:

```
  <div ng-repeat="x in X">  {{x|customFilter:myFilter.filterField}} </div>
```