# AngularJS Reg Ex Replace Filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I don't know of a way in Angular to switch characters out of a string and replace them using a reg ex.

I need a reg ex that will take "Hi There" and convert it to "hi_there".

I understand that I can use the [lowercase](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/lowercase) filter to achieve the "hi there" result, but I'd love to remove that space and put an underscore the instead.

Does anyone know how to do this in Angular?

Answer (score 0):

See this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227325/how-do-i-call-an-angular-js-filter-with-multiple-arguments). Details how to make a reg ex search and replace with Angular JS.