# AngularJS custom filter unknown provider error

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I created this filter to transform `userID` to user's name:

```
angular.module('idToName', ['userService'])

.filter('idToName', function(User) {
  User.allUsers()
  .success(function(data) {
    userData = data;
  });
  var assignee;
  return function(IDs) {
    for (var j = 0; j < userData.length; i++) {
      for (var i = 0; i < IDs.length; j++){
        if (IDs[i] == userData[j]._id) {
          assignee[i] = userData[j].firstname + ' ' + userData[j].lastname + ' ' + userData[j].cname;
        }
      }
    }
    return assignee;
  }
})
```

It takes in an array of `userIDs`, and it should find the corresponding `userData` object and return its names.

But when I run it, it gets this error:

```
Error: $injector:unpr
Unknown Provider

Unknown provider: idToNameFilterProvider
```

So what did I do wrong? I would appreciate any help.

Comment: How do you use `idToName`?

Comment: Your `userData` is obtained asyncly, when you call the filter, the `userData` may not have arrived yet.

Comment: Separate issue. If the IDs are what you are searching for, then IDs should be the outer loop and userData the inner loop. Then put a break inside the if statement so you don't continue to look for a match after you find it.

Comment: The error is coming from the code that is trying to use the filter, not the filter itself. Either the Javascript file with the filter in it is not loaded (or if using AMD, the module isn't being required), or the `idToName` module isn't listed as a dependency.

Comment: filter needs to be synchronous. Use arguments to pass in data that will be received later then just check if that argument is defined or not

Comment: @Joy I just use it on the html where I list the user's ID. Basically {{eachUser._id | idToName}}

Comment: @Joy How should I change it to make it run synchronously then?

Comment: @ach is most likely correct concerning the question as asked. The other suggestions will fix a problem that will appear once you have properly included the file and injected the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check working demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bbyj308h/1/)

```
angular.module('idToName', [])
    .factory('userService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var users = [];
    return {
        all: function () {
            return $http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
        }
    };
}])
    .filter('idToName', function () {
    var assignee = [];
    return function (userData, IDs) {
        if (!userData || userData.length === 0) {
            return 'loading...';
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < userData.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < IDs.length; j++) {
                if (IDs[j] == userData[i].id) {
                    assignee[i] = userData[i].name + ' ' + userData[i].username + ' ';
                }
            }
        }
        return assignee;
    }
})
    .controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'userService', function ($scope, userService) {
    $scope.IDs = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    $scope.users = [];
    userService.all().success(function (data) {
        $scope.users = data;
    });
}]);
```

Use it in HTML:

```
<div ng-app="idToName" ng-controller='MyCtrl'>{{ users | idToName:IDs }}</div>
```

Some issues in your code:

1. Your `userData` is obtained asyncly, when you call the filter, the `userData` may not have arrived yet. And your filter should not be fetching data. Because it is not its job. You'd better separate the data-fetching logic to some independent logic. So I created another service `userService`
2. You nested `for` loop is messed with the `i` and `j` variables. I have made them working.
3. `idToName` is not a good module name.

---

#### Update 1

Learned from comments of @tuckerjt07 and @ach, please check your JavaScript inclusion and module dependency code. There must be something wrong when trying to inject the filter. Seems the filter itself is not found within the context.

Comment: While valid it doesn't address the issue as represented in the question. The asynchronous call wouldn't throw an injector error.

Comment: @tuckerjt07 I tried to clear out the problem regarding mixing async calls and filters. Em, there must be something wrong when calling the filter, which causes the injector error. But we don't have the full picture. That might be solved upon question owners' investigation into his/her code.

Comment: the error he gave us matches perfectly with what ach suggested to fix it.

Comment: Wow thanks for the help guys. I've tried the method @Joy and @ ach suggested. I fixed the issue @ ach mentioned, that was indeed a silly mistake. But as for your jsFiddle, it seems that the filter isn't even used or working cuz your html is just showing users rather than ID

Comment: @thousight Here `{{ users | idToName:IDs }}` calls the filter to work. The `$http` call gets the `user` objects only.

Comment: @Joy But what I need is actually {{ _id | idToName: IDs }} cuz I need to transfer my IDs to its corresponding name. Also, I don't get how you put 2 params into the filter, cuz when I try it on my code, it could only take the first param. Sorry I'm newbie

Comment: Also isn't {{ users | idToName:IDs }} calling $scope.users instead of $scope.IDs?

Comment: @thousight for multiple arguments to a filter, check [How do I call an Angular.js filter with multiple arguments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227325/how-do-i-call-an-angular-js-filter-with-multiple-arguments). In the JSFiddle, I use `IDs` as the argument. Of course you can switch the `users` and `IDs` ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bbyj308h/2/)). I don't know what `_id` is in your comment.

Comment: That was actually $scope.IDs on your JSFiddle

Comment: I think my last comment gives what you want. This question can be closed.