# Angular - Filter Params

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

How do I pass multiple arguments into a filter?

Trying the following

```
mylist = $filter('filter')(array, {'field': 'param1'} ||  {'field': 'param2'} );
```

but this only uses the first filter param rather than both.

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227325/how-do-i-call-an-angular-js-filter-with-multiple-arguments

Comment: Are you trying to filter array where `field == param1 || field == param2` ?

Comment: Here is a possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868248/how-to-filter-multiple-values-or-operation-in-angularjs

Comment: @prince yes I am. Thought it would be possible without writing a custom filter.

Comment: You would likely have to customize this, but you can pass a function  $filter('filter')(array, function(v,i) { return v.field == 'param1' || v.field == 'param2'; } ) https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter