# How to add more than one argument in a custom filter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The following filter make an ng-repeat only show `pano`s with `isOutRoom` `true`:

```
<tr ng-if="building.pano.length" ng-repeat="pano in panos | filter: filterByRoom">

$scope.filterByRoom = function(pano, room) {
  return pano.isOutRoom === true
}
```

I also want to do have another ng-repeat that only shows `pano`s with `isVirtualRoom` set to `true`.

How to add a second argument to the filter so I can choose between `isOutRoom` and `isVirtualRoom`?

I tried this:

```
<tr ng-if="building.pano.length" ng-repeat="pano in panos | filter: filterByRoom: pano.isOutRoom)"

$scope.filterByRoom = function(pano, room) {
  return pano.room === true
```

But now nothing shows in the ng-repeat.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/HHEVO24V75gwEivPooyx?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can seperate parameters using `:`

`filter: filterByRoom : secondArg : thirdArg`

Edit: looks like this post answers the question in more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16227326/841804

Comment: Weird I tried `<tr ng-if="building.pano.length" ng-repeat="pano in panos | filter: filterByRoom:isOutRoom)">` and
`<tr ng-if="building.pano.length" ng-repeat="pano in panos | filter: filterByRoom:pano:isOutRoom)">` and nothing is showing.

Comment: I tried all the combinations. Still, can't make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Filters may have arguments. The syntax for this is

```
{{ expression | filter:argument1:argument2:... }}
```

E.g. the markup {{ 1234 | number:2 }} formats the number 1234 with 2 decimal points using the number filter. The resulting value is 1,234.00.

docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter

Comment: The docs show this: `{{ expression | filter:argument1:argument2:... }}` But mine looks more like `{{ expression | filter:filterName:argument1:argument2:... }}` But that doesn't work.

Comment: @alexchenco Could you change it to filterName:argument1:argument2 and test that ?