# Filter with ng-repeat. pass argument with item

Tags: angularjs

I know we can filter on ng-repeat element with this syntax:

```
<li ng-repeat="v in values() | filter:myFilter ">
```

where myFilter is a function with 1 parameter (the current element).

```
function myFilter(item){
  console.log(item);
}
```

I know we can filter on ng-repeat passing objets as argument like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="v in values() | filter:myFilter(myVar) ">

function myFilter(word){
  console.log(word);
}
```

But is there a way to have a filter for ng-repeat with current element + other parameters?

this doesn't work:

```
<li ng-repeat="v in values() | filter:myFilter(v, myVar) ">
```

thanks.

Comment: [This may come in handy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227325/how-do-i-call-an-angular-js-filter-with-multiple-arguments)

Comment: where are you keeping myVar? if it in $scope it should work

Comment: I used a fiddle found on stackoverflow to show an example. http://jsfiddle.net/5VbCJ/113/. item is "undefined"