# angularjs filter with two parameters

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

OrderBy filter not work with 2nd parameter, it sort only by first parameter. Any ideas with how to solve this issue?

```
var found = $filter('orderBy')($scope.statusHistory, ['Id', { IsCreatedByMember: true}], true)[0];
```

Comment: check thus http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227325/how-do-i-call-an-angular-js-filter-with-multiple-arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should use a function for expression, not an object:

```
var found = $filter('orderBy')($scope.statusHistory, [
  'Id',
  item => item.IsCreatedByMember
], true)[0];
```

Comment: well it return an item where `IsCreatedByMember` equals `false`

Comment: Of course. But the array is going to be sorted by `Id` first and then by `IsCreatedByMember` for items with same `Id`. If it's not what you are after, then you need to explain better.

Comment: I need to get item, which sorted by descending by two parameters: `Id` and 2nd parameter `IsCreatedByMember`

Comment: Yes, above code does exactly this: largest `Id` and `IsCreatedByMember` true. This is what you need?

Comment: It returns the largest `Id` with `IsCreatedByMember` false

Comment: Can you reproduce it in plunkr? Works for me: http://plnkr.co/edit/nQgitbRJ7rZN0V7DufJE?p=preview

Comment: Then you don't want to sort by two fields. You need to filter by `IsCreatedByMember: true` and then sort by `Id`: http://plnkr.co/edit/j1lGzbG2aMGlYDGH76z9?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You should try like this :

```
$filter('orderBy')( $scope.statusHistory, $scope.var1, $scope.var2);
```