# use service function with ng-bind-html in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services, ng-bind-html

I'm trying to use a transformation function called `highlightReview` defined in a **AngularJS** service with the attribute `ng-bind-html` but I can't make it work.

See below for a sample :

```
function myReputationSrvc($http, $q, $log, $sce) {

    this.highlightReview = function(text) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
    }
}
```

then in the HTML there is a call to that function like the following :

```
<span ng-bind-html = " MyReputationSrvc.highlightReview(review.positiveText) "> </span>
```

Nothing is called and no errors are thrown, it seems like that `ng-bind-html` is working just with functions or variables in the `$scope` context, since if I move the function to the `$scope` and then call it with `ng-bind-html = "highlightReview(review.positiveText)"` is working correctly.

*Is there a way to use the function from the service? **I've put the function in the service because I want to share this function among multiple controllers.***

AngularJS version is : 1.6.5 .

Comment: I would suggest the `filter`-based solution instead, which is pretty elegant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19705096/1225328.

Comment: @sp00m What if I need to pass 2 arguments instead of one to the function? Let's say the text and another argument, can I still use a filter ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Would you mind providing your actual code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to inject the service to your controller and place the function inside the controller, you cannot call the service function directly from the template.

Or you could have your own filter to do the job,

```
.filter('mysce',function($http, $q, $log, $sce){  
     return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
});

<span ng-bind-html = "review.positiveText | mysce"> </span>
```

Comment: I have already injected the service inside the controller, I can use other functions inside the controller itself

Comment: use a common filter as above

Comment: @Sajeetharan You saved ma life! :hugs:

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make this common, instead of using service, you can use a `filter`

```
.filter('convertHtml',function($sce){
  return function(text){
     return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
 }
})


<span ng-bind-html = "review.positiveText | convertHtml "> </span>
```

Comment: What if I need to pass two arguments to the function ? Can I still use a filter ? How can I call it then ?

Comment: you can. check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227325/how-do-i-call-an-angular-js-filter-with-multiple-arguments

Answer (score 0):

From the AngularJS docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

If you inject `ngSanitize` to the module you're using you can just use `ng-bind-html` passing a string parameter whose value is HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Can you have a look at this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/O8lvz48ZtAgtzJOaNyRD) as you have a example code snippet I have with that plunker [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/O8lvz48ZtAgtzJOaNyRD)

Sample Code:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'MyReputationSrvc', function($scope, MyReputationSrvc) {
  $scope.positiveText = "Hello </br> <b>World</b>";
  $scope.MyReputation = function(repText){
    return MyReputationSrvc.highlightReview(repText);
  };
}]);
```