# $index in table angularjs

Tags: angularjs, filter, indexing

I am using http://simplydo.com/projector/ for my current project. I want to create custom filters for table columns which shows only months which crosses the given filter value. I have done some coding which is working good but the months in the table are always staring form first month instead of real filtered data.

Can some one help me how i can change this to display the respective months according the filter value?

```
<tr ng-repeat="change in montlyProjection() | filter:greatnum">{{change}}
          <td>{{getMonthLabel($index+1)}}</td>
          <td class="number">{{roundDown(change)}}</td>
          <td class="number" ng-class="positiveNegative(convertToNumber(startBalance) + change)">{{roundDown(convertToNumber(startBalance) + change)}}</td>
        </tr>
```

### in JS

$scope.greatnum=function(item){

```
      return  item > $scope.lowerbound;
      }
```

Comment: DO you mean to ask why your filter is not working and why the table entries are shown without applying the filter even though your `ng-repeat` directive contains the filter?

Comment: I got it now by using ng-show directive....any way thanks guys i found it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17584240/index-in-table-not-sequential-angularjs?rq=1