# Use ng-repeat for only some items of a collection

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I use the ng-repeat directive to print out all posts for a user.

```
<div ng-repeat="post in user.posts">
  <p>{{ post.content }}</p>
</div>
```

I want to limit this to just printing out posts that have an "is_public" attribute equal to "true".  How can I do this?

```
<div ng-repeat="post in user.posts ??? if post.public == true">
  <p>{{ post.content }}</p>
</div>
```

I've seen the use of `filter` with ng-repeat, but it looks like it's meant for dynamic filtering, not a case where I know what the filter should always be.

Comment: Just filter it out in the controller, use native filter.

Comment: In this situation, I need to filter it in the view. Is it possible? (The question is a simplification of what I'm actually dealing with)

Comment: Then just use angular [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter). `ng-repeat="post in user.posts | filter:{public:true}"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11996857/how-to-use-parameters-within-the-filter-in-angularjs , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17793751/how-to-filter-by-object-property-in-angularjs