# Can't get filter to work in ng-repeat with multiple parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've used filters in my app before, but this is the first time I've needed to send extra parameters to the filter. There seems to be an implicit parameter that gets passed to the filter when used like this:

```
ng-options="t as t.TeamName for t in (teamList | filter: filterTeams) track by t.TeamId">
```

In my controller I have:

```
        $scope.filterTeams = function (team) {
            if ($scope.EU.selectedUsersDepartment && !isEmpty($scope.selectedUsersDepartment)) {
                return (team.Department.DepartmentId === $scope.EU.selectedUsersDepartment.DepartmentId);
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        };
```

`team` seems to be passed to `filterTeams` implicitly.

When I try to extend this idea with multiple parameters it fails:

```
ng-repeat="listEntry in (list | filter: filterByDay(listEntry, 1))"
```

Controller code:

```
        $scope.filterByDay = function (listEntry, dayOffset) {
            return isDateEqual(listEntry.myDate, addDays($scope.NIC.selectedWeek, dayOffset)) ||
                   isDateEqual(listEntry.myOtherDate, addDays($scope.NIC.selectedWeek, dayOffset));
        };
```

`listEntry` is always undefined, but `dayOffset` comes through fine. It seems explicit passing of the array element fails, but having any kind of parameter in the template also destroys the implicit passing.

I've tried alternative syntax as suggested in this answer:

[How do I call an Angular.js filter with multiple arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227325/how-do-i-call-an-angular-js-filter-with-multiple-arguments)

```
ng-repeat="listEntry in (list | filterByDay: listEntry:1)"
```

However this also fails.

This next answer discusses an option of using a dedicated angular filter in option 2:

[How to use parameters within the filter in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11996857/how-to-use-parameters-within-the-filter-in-angularjs)

But I'm not clear on the difference between a function attached to `$scope` being used as a filter and adding a filter to my root app module, nor does the example demonstrate how to pass multiple parameters.

I also tried following this answer which suggests returning a function in your filter:

[Passing arguments to angularjs filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753321/passing-arguments-to-angularjs-filters)

I modified my ng-repeat to this:

```
ng-repeat="listEntry in (list | filter: filterByDay(1))"
```

And my `filterByDay` function to this:

```
        $scope.filterByDay = function (dayOffset) {
            return function (listEntry) {
                console.log('listEntry: ');
                console.log(listEntry);
                console.log('dayOffset: ');
                console.log(dayOffset);
                return isDateEqual(listEntry.myDate, addDays($scope.NIC.selectedWeek, dayOffset)) ||
                    isDateEqual(listEntry.myOtherDate, addDays($scope.NIC.selectedWeek, dayOffset));
            }
        };
```

This seems to prevent the function returned by filterByDay from working, with none of the `console.log` statements executing.

Comment: the last one should work for sure, please provide working [plunker](https://plnkr.co) example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to get filters working with multiple parameters but I found an alternative that works just as well.

Replace:

```
ng-repeat="listEntry in (list | filter: filterByDay(1))"
```

with

```
ng-repeat="listEntry in getFilteredList(list,1)"
```

`getFilteredList` is a function attached to `$scope` in my controller that iterates over `list` and returns an array of just the elements I want.