# How to add dynamic column in ng-repeat filter

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Is it possible to add a dynamic column `filter:{'Is'+dType.Name:true}` in `ng-repeat` filter?

```
<option ng-repeat="option in mainCtrl.Maps | filter:{'Is'+dType.Name:true}" ng-value="option.Id">{{option.Name}}</option>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Angular will throw an error. But you can use a function instead and that function can work with dynamic attributes, e.g.:

```
<option ng-repeat="option in mainCtrl.Maps | filter:filterFn" ng-value="option.Id">{{option.Name}}</option>
```

And in the controller:

```
$scope.filterFn = function(option) {
  var propName = 'Is' + $scope.dType.Name; // assuming that dType is somewhere in the scope
  return option[propName] === true; // this replaces the shorthand filter in the ng-repeat
}
```

**EDIT** (due to additional details that were not part of the original question):

If you want to pass an additional parameter to your filter function you can use something I found in the following SO answer: [How to use parameters within the filter in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17813983/634872)

Adapted to your case:

```
<option ng-repeat="option in mainCtrl.Maps | filter:filterFn(dType)" ng-value="option.Id">{{option.Name}}</option>
```

And in the controller:

```
$scope.filterFn = function(dType) {
  return function (option) {
    var propName = 'Is' + dType.Name; // dType is passed as parameter
    return option[propName] === true; 
  };
};
```

In short, your filter function has to return a function with the signature that is expected by Angular (function with one parameter: element of `ng-repeat`), but because of the wrapping it can also handle additional parameters.

Comment: `dType.Name` is inside an `ng-repeat`. Since I need to pass the `dType.Name` I tried it like this `filter:{mainCtrl.getDType(dType.Name):true}`. Adding the `===true` inside the function doesn't filter it.

Comment: @klent I added an option that should cover your case.

Comment: I didn't add `option` in the function so it didn't work when I tried it before. It filters now. Thanks!