# How do i filter name in ng-repeat angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

Currently, if I filter, the BookingID and Product I see that filtered result in UI. How do I have to add a filter for a name? because this name is coming from another array and getting it based on id

need to add filter based on BookingID, Product and name fields
Here's my code:

```
<div ng-app="datatable" ng-controller="datacontroller">
<md-card>
        <div layout="row" style="height:50px; vertical-align: middle;">
            <md-input-container md-no-float class="md-block" flex="85" >
                
                <input ng-model="searchBooking" type="text" placeholder="Search">
            </md-input-container>
           
        </div>
    </md-card>
  <md-table-container>
    <table md-table>
      <thead md-head md-order="filter">
        <tr md-row>
          <th md-column><span>BookingID</span></th>
          <th md-column><span>Product</span></th>
          <th md-column><span>Name</span></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody md-body>
        <tr md-row ng-repeat="row in filterBooking() | orderBy:filter">
          <td md-cell>{{row.BookingID}}</td>
          <td md-cell>{{row.Product}}</td>
          <td>
          <md-select ng-model="row.UserID" ng-change="test(row)">
              <md-option ng-repeat="user in users" ng-value="user.id">{{user.name}}</md-option>
            </md-select>
                    </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </md-table-container>
</div>
```

controller

```
angular.module("datatable", ['ngRoute', 'ngMaterial', 'md.data.table']).controller("datacontroller", ['$scope', function($scope) {
   $scope.bookings = [
    {
    "BookingID":1,
    "Product":"test",
    "Shop":"A",
    "ContactNumber":124,
    "UserID":1
    },
    {
    "BookingID":2,
    "Product":"bgh",
    "Shop":"d",
    "ContactNumber":345,
    "UserID":2
    }
  ];
  
  $scope.users = [
    {
    "id":1,
    "name":"abc"
    },
    {
    "id":2,
    "name":"xyz"
    
    }
  ]
  
  $scope.searchBooking = '';
        $scope.filterBooking = function () {
            return $scope.bookings.filter(function (item) {
                return (
                    item.BookingID.toString().indexOf($scope.searchBooking) > -1|| 
                    ( item.Product.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.searchBooking.toLowerCase()) > -1)
                    
                );
            });
        };
}]);
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nawuhxj1/1/)

[image]

Please advice

user name comes from a different array so I'm not sure how should filter name

Comment: One side note, Ask your project owner to move to angular 13

Comment: @brk why is there any specific reason?

Comment: @brk how is that relevant to this question?

Comment: @mindthefrequency google have stopped providing support to angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so if you first add a 'name' property to every object in your bookings array, having its value cross matched from your 'users' array, this will make your life easier as you can then filter like:

```
<tr md-row ng-repeat="row in filterBooking() | orderBy:'+name'">
```

'name' being the new property in each of your objects, and + indicating an ascending order.

Adding the 'name' property to the items of your bookings array can be done with a simple for loop.

```
for (var i=0; i<$scope.bookings.length; i++) {
   $scope.bookings[i].name = $scope.users.filter(function(_){ _.id === $scope.bookings[i].UserID })[0].name;
}
```