# Angular.js ng-repeat filter by property having one of multiple values (OR of values)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

Is it possible to filter an array of objects, such that the value of property can be either of a few values (OR condition) **without writing a custom filter**

This is similar to this problem - [Angular.js ng-repeat :filter by single field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733136/angular-js-ng-repeat-filter-by-single-field)

But instead of

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products | filter: { color: 'red' }">
```

is it possible to do something like this

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products | filter: { color: 'red'||'blue' }">
```

for a sample data as follows-

```
$scope.products = [
   { id: 1, name: 'test', color: 'red' },
   { id: 2, name: 'bob', color: 'blue' }
   /*... etc... */
];
```

I've unsuccessfully tried

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products | filter: { color: ('red'||'blue') }">
```

Comment: Might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868248/how-to-filter-multiple-values-or-operation-in-angularjs

Comment: refer my answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27606595/ngrepeat-filter-by-deep-property/39523973#39523973

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter multiple values (OR operation) in angularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868248/how-to-filter-multiple-values-or-operation-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Best way to do this is to use a function:

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products | filter: myFilter">

$scope.myFilter = function (item) { 
    return item === 'red' || item === 'blue'; 
};
```

Alternatively, you can use [ngHide or ngShow](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) to dynamically show and hide elements based on a certain criteria.

Comment: Apart from a function or a custom filter is there no way to do it inline?
ngHide will set the `display` to `none`, but the `div` will get generated and inserted into the DOM. Anyway I think function is the cleanest way to do it, was only curious if there was a syntax to specify an OR condition inline.

Comment: @Sherlock To be more precise, you should add the color attribute :  

`$scope.myFilter = function (item) { 
    return item.color === 'red' || item.color === 'blue'; 
};`

Answer (score 41):

For me, it worked as given below:

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products | filter: { color: 'red'||'blue' }">

<div ng-repeat="product in products | filter: { color: 'red'} | filter: { color:'blue' }">
```

Comment: Would this not be more like an "and" condition?

Answer (score 17):

I thing `ng-if` should work:

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products" ng-if="product.color === 'red' 
|| product.color === 'blue'">
```

Comment: This works, but `$index` will refer to original array index

Answer (score 11):

In HTML:

`<div ng-repeat="product in products | filter: colorFilter">`

In Angular:

```
$scope.colorFilter = function (item) { 
  if (item.color === 'red' || item.color === 'blue') {
  return item;
 }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, but if you read the question carefully I wanted a solution **without writing a custom filter**

Answer (score 8):

Here is a way to do it while passing in an extra argument:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17813797/4533488 (thanks to Denis Pshenov)

```
<div ng-repeat="group in groups">
    <li ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:weDontLike(group.enemy.name)">
        <span>{{friend.name}}</span>
    <li>
</div>
```

With the backend:

```
$scope.weDontLike = function(name) {
    return function(friend) {
        return friend.name != name;
    }
}
```

.

---

And yet another way with an in-template filter only:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12528093/4533488 (thanks to mikel)

```
<div ng:app>
  <div ng-controller="HelloCntl">
    <ul>
       <li ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:{name:'!Adam'}">
            <span>{{friend.name}}</span>
            <span>{{friend.phone}}</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I found a more generic [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31006538/1784230) with the most angular-native solution I can think. Basically you can pass your own comparator to the default `filterFilter` function. Here's  [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/INHgnStQof8nT2f6tk7X?p=preview) as well.

Answer (score -1):

After not able to find a good universal solution I made something of my own. I have not tested it for a very large list.

It takes care of nested keys,arrays or just about anything.

Here is the [github](https://github.com/rajnandan1/xurple-filter) and [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rajnandan1/keq9zrjd/13/)

```
app.filter('xf', function() {
    function keyfind(f, obj) {
        if (obj === undefined)
            return -1;
        else {
            var sf = f.split(".");
            if (sf.length <= 1) {
                return obj[sf[0]];
            } else {
                var newobj = obj[sf[0]];
                sf.splice(0, 1);
                return keyfind(sf.join("."), newobj)
            }
        }

    }
    return function(input, clause, fields) {
        var out = [];
        if (clause && clause.query && clause.query.length > 0) {
            clause.query = String(clause.query).toLowerCase();
            angular.forEach(input, function(cp) {
                for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
                    var haystack = String(keyfind(fields[i], cp)).toLowerCase();
                    if (haystack.indexOf(clause.query) > -1) {
                        out.push(cp);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            })
        } else {
            angular.forEach(input, function(cp) {
                out.push(cp);
            })
        }
        return out;
    }

})
```

HTML

```
<input ng-model="search.query" type="text" placeholder="search by any property">
<div ng-repeat="product in products |  xf:search:['color','name']">
...
</div>
```