# ngRepeat Filter by deep property

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

If I have a complex object with objects as property values, how can I filter by one of the nested properties?

Can this be done with the OOB ng-repeat filter?

**Data**

```
{
  Name: 'John Smith',
  Manager: {
     id: 123,
     Name: 'Bill Lumburg'
  }
}
```

**ngRepeat**

```
<li ng-repeat="e in emps | filter:Manager.Name">{{ e.Name }}</li>
```

Answer (score 116, accepted):

You need to pass in the argument to filter by:

```
<input ng-model="filter.key">
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="e in list | filter: {Manager: {Name: filter.key}}">
    {{e.Name}}  (Manager: {{e.Manager.Name}})
  </li>
</ul>
```

[Example on Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7KlAX1XmwdUyUMnk6XlJ?p=preview)

Comment: If some objects have no manager property they won't appear even if the filter is empty. Do you know a way to include them ?

Comment: what if Name is an array and i want to filter First-Name only ?

Comment: @Bludwarf http://plnkr.co/edit/dMbYapbySJMGKiykvpG7?p=preview maybe this can help someone

Answer (score 2):

If you are filtering multiple properties then the syntax would be similar to below.

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in list | {filter: top_object_property_name: value, top_object_property_with_nested_objects_name: {nested_object_property_name: value}}">
       ...
  </li>
</ul>
```

eg:

```
        var employees = [name: 'John', roles: [{roleName: 'Manager'},{roleName: 'Supervisor'}]];

        <li ng-repeat="staff in employees | {filter: name: 'John', roles: {roleName: 'Manager'}}">
              ...
        </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

In latest version of angularjs nested obj filter implemented by default.can use filter normally.
It for angular 1 only

Comment: Dear @Murali above solution is just for angular 1.

Comment: @Murali I am using Angular 4 but not able to filter the records as normal

Answer (score 1):

**To filter with multiple deep property we need to create custom filter.
What i mean we need to create our own function to filter the data in object and return the required object(filtered object).**

For example i need to filter data from below object -

```
[
{
   "document":{
      "documentid":"1",
      "documenttitle":"test 1",
      "documentdescription":"abcdef"
       }
},
{
   "document":{
      "documentid":"2",
      "documenttitle":"dfjhkjhf",
      "documentdescription":"dfhjshfjdhsj"
       }
}
]
```

In HTML we use ng-repeat to show document list -

```
<div>
   //search input textbox
   <input ng-model="searchDocument" placeholder="Search">
 </div>
<div ng-repeat="document in documentList | filter: filteredDocument">
   //our html code 
</div>
```

In Controller we write filter function to return filtered object by using two properties of object which are "documenttitle" and "documentdescription", code example is as below -

```
function filterDocuments(document)
        {
            if($scope.searchDocument)
            {
                     if(document.documentTitle.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.searchDocument.toLowerCase()) !== -1 || document.document.shortDescription.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.searchDocument.toLowerCase()) !== -1)
                {
                    //returns filtered object
                    return document
                }
            }else {
               return document;
            }
        }
```

Where $scope.searchDocument is the scope variable which binded to the search textbox (HTML input tag) in which user can input the text to search.

Comment: I find this answer very confusing. How does it answer the question?

Comment: Dear Sir (@Jason Swett), When we have array of object and that object have an another object property in it for example "document" property of array object then we need to create custom filter in the controller to implement the "search" like functionality.