# AngularJS filter on multiple deep nested properties

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I've couple of select fields on basis of which I want to filter data. Here is working plukr: http://plnkr.co/edit/VUnAoL2Sl0IqGcZqHbbi?p=preview

If I select any one value from select, it works fine, but when I select the other one it don't show any data.

These filters are going to be dynamic (depending on number of columns) So I want that in HTML I could use it with single filter declaration like: `<tr ng-repeat="row in data | filter:{columns: filt}">`

Not like: `<tr ng-repeat="row in data | filter:{columns: filt.something} | filter: {some: thing}">`

Comment: Create your own custom filter https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-custom-angularjs-filters

Comment: Also, filter supports function as expression parameter. I guess it will be one awesome function but I think it would work - https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.17/docs/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: refer my answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27606595/ngrepeat-filter-by-deep-property/39523973#39523973

Answer (score 0):

```
    <tr ng-repeat="row in _data = (data | filter:{columns: {dealType:filt.dealType}}) | filter:{columns:{primaryUse:filt.primaryUse}}">
       <td ng-repeat="column in row.columns">
           {{column[column.header]}}
       </td>
   </tr>
```

I have got the same issue and it worked with a change in your code as above. Thanks