# Angular - Filtering an ng-repeat by Item.User._id

Tags: angularjs

Im trying to filter an ng-repeat by an id value.

```
$scope.filter = $stateParams.id;  --> 56a1832a36dc3d0e00c7aa3f
```

Heres the model for the Item Object with relevant vlues

```
var ItemSchema = new Schema({

  title: {
    type: String,
    maxlength: 150
  }
  user: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }

});
```

How exactly do i filter the Items by the user._id ?

My attempt which is giving no results.

```
<div ng-repeat="saving in savings| filter: {user : 'filter'}">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://plnkr.co/edit/sihBuRe9vNKO0jB1Wk8b

The [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) explain using filters very well. The filter filters the array by property you pass to it. If it's an object, it will match its properties against each item in the array. This means that item in array with property `user: {_id: 2}` will be shown.

```
<div ng-repeat="saving in savings | filter:{user: {_id: 2}}">{{saving.title}}</div>
```

You can checkout [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27606595/ngrepeat-filter-by-deep-property) for another example.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I just have a small problem with casting i assume. <div ng-repeat="saving in savings | filter:{user: {_id: 'usernamevalue'}}"> doesnt work but <div ng-repeat="saving in savings | filter:{user: {_id: '56a1832a36dc3d0e00c7aa3f'}}"> does. Is there something slightly wrong with the comparison?

Comment: Looks good to me. Make sure the user with `_id: 'usernamevalue'` actually exists.

Comment: i needed to remove the ' ' is all. Thanks for the help.