# ngRepeat filter by array-property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

If I have an object with a property that is an array, how can I filter by the first element of this property?

**Data**

```
{
    Id: "0",
    Name: ["John", "Doe"]
}
```

**ngRepeat**

```
<li ng-repeat="u in users | filter:{Name[0]: 'John'}">{{ u.Name[0] + ' ' + u.Name[1] }}</li>
```

Comment: You probably need a custom filter to achieve this. [custom filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09)

Comment: This has an answer [in here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27606595/ngrepeat-filter-by-deep-property)

Comment: thank you nubinub :D i think i've found the solution, but i will wait to see if there are any hacks that doesn't require custom filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly modified from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32994920/6184698) to work with arrays:

```
<li ng-repeat="u in users | filter: {Name: ['John']}">{{ u.Name[0] + ' ' + u.Name[1] }}</li>
```

---

**Update:** This doesn't seem to work after version 1.2.1 or so. You can see the difference in [this fiddle using v1.2.1](https://jsfiddle.net/gsvnty6d/) and [this one using v1.4.8](https://jsfiddle.net/gsvnty6d/1/). Not sure what's changed between these two or if the feature was ever even officially supported. As an alternative, you could use a function predicate, like so:

```
<li ng-repeat="u in users | filter: isJohn">{{ u.Name[0] + ' ' + u.Name[1] }}</li>
```

controller:

```
$scope.isJohn = function(value){
    return value.Name[0] === 'John';
};
```

But then again, that's not much simpler than creating a custom filter like *nubinub* suggested in the comments, and definitely less reusable.

Comment: this doesnt work, it will works if i have 2 property FirstName and LastName, then i can filter like that SO answer, but i have an array-property

Comment: Did you try the modified version I wrote?

Comment: @nmtuan The code snippet in this answer should work on your array just fine

Comment: I tried your code on jsfiddle but it doesnt work, also tested on my own project https://jsfiddle.net/tzbgvzm2/1/

Comment: @nmtuan Ah, you're right. I seem to have used an old version of angular when testing the original answer. My bad. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<li ng-repeat="u in users | filter:u.Name[0] == 'John'">{{ u.Name[0] + ' ' + u.Name[1] }}</li>
```

Comment: hmm how do i expect that u.Name[0] equals something ?

Comment: i want to filter out all the users that have his/her first-name (e.g Name[0]) equals 'John', with your expression i dont know where to put the filter-key 'John'