# Angularjs accessing object index

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to check the state of a property (true or false), on each object to determine weather or not to display a div.

For example, the following works great. Show "Student" heading if `students.length > 0`, then greet each student by name individually.

```
<div ng-if="ctrl.classroomInfo.students.length > 0">
  <h1>Students</h1>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="student in ctrl.classroomInfo.students">
      Welcome, {{student}}!
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

But what if I wanted to add another condition? I only want to show this classroomInfo `<div>` if **atleast one** student has good grades.

```
 <div ng-if="ctrl.classroomInfo.students.length > 0 &&
   ctrl.classroomInfo.students[$index].hasGoodGrades === true">
      <h1>Students</h1>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="student in ctrl.classroomInfo.students">
          Welcome, {{student}}!
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

In the above code block I have added `students[$index].hasGoodGrades === true`, but `$index` only works in combination with `ng-repeat`. Meaning I would need to add:

`ng-repeat="student in ctrl.classroomInfo.students"` to my `div` tag. This is bad because it will repeat the `<h1>Students</h1>` header for each student with good grades.

How can I access the **hasGoodGrades** property on each student object to determine weather or not to show this entire div?

**UPDATE:**

Thanks for the answers regarding filters. How do I handle a case where the filtered property is another level deep? For example:

`ctrl.classroomInfo.students.RESULTS.hasGoodGrades`

`ng-if="(ctrl.classroomInfo.students | filter:{RESULTS.hasGoodGrades:true}).length > 0"` doesn't work

Comment: You'd do it *within* the `li` for each student. It doesn't make any sense to put it where you've put it, as that's *outside* the loop.

Comment: to answer the question about the nested filter property try this `filter:{ RESULTS: { hasGoodGrades:true }}` src - http://stackoverflow.com/a/32994920/1121919

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a filter:

```
<div ng-if="(ctrl.classroomInfo.students | filter:{hasGoodGrades:true}).length > 0">
```

Comment: How does this work when the property is chained another level deep? For example `ctrl.classroomInfo.students.results.hasGoodGrades` would the filter be written as `| filter:{results.hasGoodGrades:true}` or is that wrong? Asking because that didn't work for me

Comment: @bruh I think in case of nested properties you need to provide a function (instead of an object) as your filter expression. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter for argument details.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this either by creating a filter that returns a boolean OR a controller method that returns a boolean.  I advocate using a filter to keep your view controllers DRY.

```
.filter( 'hasGoodGrades', [
    function(){
        return function( students ){
            if( students && students.length )
            {
                 var i = 0, m = students.length, student
                 for( i; i < m; i++ )
                 {
                      student = students[ i ]
                      if( student.hasGoodGrades )
                           return true
                 }
            }

            return false
        }
    }
])
```

Use the filter in your `ng-if` like this:

```
 <div ng-if="ctrl.classroomInfo.students | hasGoodGrades">
```

#### EDIT

I'll leave the answer here as an alternative to the other answer.  Mine is a little more explicit and more readable, but I think I prefer @jstell's answer better - https://stackoverflow.com/a/39129784/1121919

Comment: Thanks for this. I will need to refactor to a solution like this, once I get it working with one of the other inline responses.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a filter in your ng-if or ng-show condition, like this:

```
    <div ng-show="(ctrl.classroomInfo.students | filter:filter(condition)).length">

      <div ng-repeat="student in ctrl.classroomInfo.students">
        {{student.name}}
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To do the test inside the loop:

```
<div ng-if="ctrl.classroomInfo.students.length > 0">
   <h1>Students</h1>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="student in ctrl.classroomInfo.students">
          <span ng-if="student.hasGoodGrades === true">Welcome, {{student}}!</span>
       </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

but the structure for each class will be created...

Comment: This will still show the classroomInfo div if no students have good grades.

Comment: "but the structure for each class will be created..." so yes.