# Angular js filter for JSON key/value nested object is not working for me

Tags: angularjs, json, filter

My JSON data looks like the below code. Can you any one please help me to filter data by code/desc which is in the state property.

```
$scope.agent =
{
    "0d297c1711de":
    [{
        "applicationName": "rewards-accounts", "agentId": "0d297c1711de",
        "status": { "agentId": "0d297c1711de", "eventTimestamp": 1510580172247, "state": { "code": 100, "desc": "Running" } }
    }],
    "16f279d66923":
    [{
        "applicationName": "rewards-accounts-details", "agentId": "16f279d66923",
        "status": { "agentId": "0d297c1711de", "eventTimestamp": 1510580172247, "state": { "code": 201, "desc": "Unexpected Shutdown" } }
    }],
    "203b353d32ef":
    [{
        "applicationName": "rewards-accounts-details", "agentId": "203b353d32ef",
        "status": { "agentId": "0d297c1711de", "eventTimestamp": 1510580172247, "state": { "code": 200, "desc": "Shutdown" } }
    }]
};
```

I have used this filter in ng-repeat . It is not working. selectedCode is my model data to be filtered.

```
| filter:{status:{ state: { code: **selectedCode**}}}
```

Comment: is your object being rendered but not getting filtered or is it not rendering and giving you `Error: [filter:notarray]` ?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27606595/ngrepeat-filter-by-deep-property)

*You need to pass in the argument to filter by*, which in your particular case looks like:

```
ng-repeat="a in agent | filter: {status: {state: {code: filter.key}}}"
```

With thanks to @Ray

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/javiros/LdoLjbqg/) for further reference.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom filter to filter your nested data,

in your controller create your filter

```
$scope.customFilter = function (row) {
    var result = false;
    if($scope.filter == undefined || $scope.filter == ""){
          result = true;
    }
    else{
         angular.forEach(row, function(value, key){
           if(value.state != undefined){
              if(value.state.code == $scope.filter)
                result = true;
           }
         });
    }
    return result;
};
```

and add this filter to your ng-repeat

```
<div ng-repeat="item in agent">
  <div ng-repeat="x in item | filter:customFilter">
    {{x}}
  </div>
</div>
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/7bR5w9hqRu0DY4GyFKsP?p=preview)

Comment: It is not working. I am not using controller. I am using directive, I added custom filter in my directive and its not working. Thanks.