# filter multiple value of one key in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have product array. I want to filter type key. I want to display only vegetables and fruits together.
How to set filter on single key and multiple value in AngularJS.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in products | filter:({type:'vegetable'}||{type:'fruit'})">{{item.name}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

    function MyCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.products = [
            {name:"Apple",type:"fruit"},
            {name:"Grape",type:"fruit"},
            {name:"Orage",type:"fruit"},
            {name:"Carrot",type:"vegetable"},
            {name:"Milk",type:"dairy"}
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to add a filter to your controller and use that:

```
$scope.filterFruitsAndVegies = function (item) {
    return item.type === 'fruit' || item.type === 'vegetable';
};
```

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in products | filter: filterFruitsAndVegies">{{item.name}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/HhZ49dpylTRJMVnSKdyt?p=preview

Comment: thanks @wayne Ellery but can we do this with out creating custom filter ?

Comment: My understanding is no. There are quite a few questions with the same answer such as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21987904/angular-js-ng-repeat-filter-by-property-having-one-of-multiple-values-or-of-val