# Filter data according to several attribute values

Tags: angularjs

I would like to filter `messages` array in a `ng-repeat` with some buttons:

- The first one **shows all** the messages.
- The second shows messages of **type A and B**.
- The last one show messages of **type C only**.

My problem is for the second button, because it has to filter on 2 differents types (A and B). I tried to filter on `['B', 'C']`, but it seems that `filter` does not accept an array of values.

---

Here is a piece of code that will allow you to better understand my issue:

```
<a ng-click="typeMsg = undefined">All</a>
<a ng-click="typeMsg = ['A', 'B']">Type A and B</a>
<a ng-click="typeMsg = 'C'">Type C</a>

<div ng-repeat="m in messages | filter: {type: typeMsg}">
    ...    
</div>
```

---

Is there a way to do this **100% in HTML**, without writing a custom filter for this case?

Comment: You cannot. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21987904/angular-js-ng-repeat-filter-by-property-having-one-of-multiple-values-or-of-val

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have `['A', 'B', 'C']` as possible values you can do `'!C'` to only show `'A'` and `'B'`. Otherwise you have to write a custom filter method.

Comment: Tried `!'C'` before posting the question, but the good syntax was `'!C'`... Grrrrr. Thanks for helping, it solved my problem ;P