# Filtering Array of Objects with Subcategories from an array of dates in Milliseconds, then ng-repeating depending upon date in calendar

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

So I have a `JSON` object of an array of objects that looks something like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Sophia Mason",
      "availability": [
        {
         "date": 1522216800000,
         "times": ["9:00 am", "2:30 pm", "5:00 pm", "6:00 pm"]
        },
        {
         "date": 1522303200000,
         "times": ["9:00 am", "2:30 pm", "5:00 pm", "6:00 pm"]
        },
        ...
      ],
     },
     .........
    ]
```

I have another array of days rendered using `moment.js` that looks something like this:

```
[1522216800000, 1522303200000, 1522389600000]
```

I need to filter the first array of objects availability by the day in each index of the date array. Then render each photographer in each day correctly in a calendar.

I am using AngularJS (by request of the client) to make something that looks like this:

[image: calendar]

I already have the days rendering by using Moment, but I am having trouble figuring out how to show each photographer per day based on their availability. To look like the calendar above.

I may be overthinking this but I have been trying to figure this out for the last few hours. Here are some of the many 'similar' answers I have looked through:

[Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38375646/filtering-array-of-objects-with-arrays-based-on-nested-value)

[Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34901593/how-to-filter-an-array-from-all-elements-of-another-array)

[Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21987904/angular-js-ng-repeat-filter-by-property-having-one-of-multiple-values-or-of-val)

Which has me only thinking of something that looks like this in my `controller.js`:

```
function setPhotographers() {

    let photographer = photographers.filter((el) => {
        el.availability.some((availability) => availability.date === today)
        .map((el)=> {
            console.log(el);
            let newEl = Object.assign({}, el);
            return newEl.availability.filter(availability => availability.date === today);
        });
    });

    return photographer;

}
```

I am still am learning a lot but this has me pretty stuck. Any help would be great! Please if you have an answer to describe why your solution works to help me better understand what you did to accomplish this.

Thanks!

Comment: The function `some` returns a boolean not an array.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track with the `.filter()`, I'm not sure why you need the `.map()`. The following should be sufficient to get you a filtered array of photographers with availability matching the `today` variable.

```
let availablePhotographers = photographers.filter((el) => el.availability.some((availability) => availability.date === today))
```

Comment: this is a good start... do you know of a way for this to dynamically update per a date? this would probably be the final step to getting it to show each day correctly on the calendar.