# ng-repeat and filter function() has variable value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My code has 4 tables and only 1 list, I used filter for this.

```html
<table><tbody><tr ng-repeat="emp in details | filter:myFilter:1"></tbody></table>
<table><tbody><tr ng-repeat="emp in details | filter:myFilter:2"></tbody></table>
<table><tbody><tr ng-repeat="emp in details | filter:myFilter:3"></tbody></table>
<table><tbody><tr ng-repeat="emp in details | filter:myFilter:4"></tbody></table>
```

And my function:

```js
$scope.myFilter = function (item, type) {
    if (item != undefined) {
        var condition1 = false;
        var condition2 = false;
        if (type == 1) {
            condition1 = item.DetailType === 'G';
            condition2 = item.IsException === false;
        }
        else if (type == 2) {
            condition1 = item.DetailType === 'E';
            condition2 = item.IsException === false;
        }
        else if (type == 3) {
            condition1 = item.DetailType === 'G';
            condition2 = item.IsException === true;
        }
        else if (type == 4) {
            condition1 = item.DetailType === 'E';
            condition2 = item.IsException === true;
        }
        return condition1 && condition2;
    }
    return false;

};
```

But I don't know why `type` variable always has a value of `0`. I can't pass a 2nd paramter to `ng-repeat`.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25552688/multiple-parameters-angular-filter-inside-ng-repeat