# AngularJs filter with "or" condition?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The code is available here: https://plnkr.co/edit/gbbsEnXxVpLsxvtKsDxw?p=preview. The filter `filter: { a : 'x' }` works and only one row is shown.

**Question:**

1. It seems `filter: { a : 'xxx' }` matches any text in `a` as long as the text contains the string `xxx`. What if I want to do exact matching?
2. How to implement: show all the rows if `a = 'xxx' or b = 3` not not use `c`?
3. Maybe it's better to use javascript code on `model.dashbardRows?

**dashboard.component.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('testModule', []) 
    .component('dashboard', {
      templateUrl: 'dashboard.component.html',
      controllerAs: 'model',
      controller: [controller] 
    });

    function controller() {
      var model = this;
      model.dashboardRows = [
        {a:'xxx', b:1, c:'ss'}, 
        {a:'yyy', b:2, c:'tt'}, 
        {a:'zzz', b:3, c:'uu'}];
    }
})();
```

**dashboard.component.html**

```
<div>
  Test
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="i in model.dashboardRows | filter: { a : 'x' }">
      <td>{{i.a}}</td>
      <td>{{i.b}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by @Valery using custom Filter is the best solution around this.

[Here is fork using custom filter(multiple conditions)](https://plnkr.co/edit/8bhJOQmy1TvBNXzzQqlI)

dashboard.component.js

```
.filter("optionalFilter",function(){
  //console.log("filter loads");
  return function(items, firstArgument,secondArgument){
    //console.log("item is ",items); // it is value upon which you have to filter
    //console.log("firstArgument is ",firstArgument);
    //console.log("secondArgument ",secondArgument);
    var filtered = [];
    angular.forEach(items, function(value, key) {
      //console.log("val ::",value);
      if(value.a == firstArgument || value.b == secondArgument){
       // console.log("val ::",value.a);
        this.push(value);
      }
    }, filtered);
    //console.log("val ::",filtered);
    return filtered;
  }
```

dashboard.component.html

```
   <tr ng-repeat="i in model.dashboardRows | optionalFilter:'aaa':2">
```

Useful references:

- [Passing arguments to angularjs filters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33604690/452708)
- [Filters](https://toddmotto.com/everything-about-custom-filters-in-angular-js/)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [filter filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) docs, you can pass in an optional `comparator` parameter.

> `true`: A shorthand for function(actual, expected) { return angular.equals(actual, expected)}. This is essentially strict comparison of expected and actual.

Note that this is case sensitive (as string comparsion is case sensitive in JS).

Also there is an example too at he bottom of the page that demonstrates filtering all or only a single property. If your filtering is complex, or your source data is big, filtering in controller can help readability and performance too.

Comment: I'm updated the question and added another property `c` in the list and I don't want `c` be used when comparing.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use custom filter

```
module.filter('myFilter', function(){
   return function(input){
      return input.filter(yourFilterFn);
   };
});

ng-repeat="item in items | myFilter"
```