# angular filter with or condtion

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, filter

For filtering a javascript array using angular filter the syntax is

**$filter('filter')(array, expression, comparator, anyPropertyKey)**

As per angular documentation the second parameter *expression* can take

> A pattern object to filter specific properties on objects
>   contained by array. For example {name:"M", phone:"1"} predicate will
>   return an array of items which have property name containing "M" and
>   property phone containing "1"

in the mentioned example we are getting condition as name matching "M" **and** phone matching "1"

but how to achieve condition as name matching "M" **or** phone matching "1"

code sample

```
var employees=[
  {lastname:"john",firstname:"jack",age:40,sex:"m"},
  {lastname:"Abby",firstname:"john",age:20,sex:"f"},
  ];

var filteredData =$filter('filter')(employees,{firstname:'john', lastname:'john'});
```

this results up with no records since and is applied
can we try to filter records having lastname or first name as 'john'

is this possible to achieve with out using custom filters

Comment: show your code and data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJs filter with "or" condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39554350/angularjs-filter-with-or-condition)

Comment: @jitender updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$filter', function($scope, $filter){

  var employees=[
  {lastname:"john",firstname:"jack",age:40,sex:"m"},
  {lastname:"Abby",firstname:"john",age:20,sex:"f"},
  {lastname:"Abby",firstname:"mark",age:20,sex:"f"},
  ];
  
$scope.filteredData = $filter('filter')(employees, function(value){
        return value.firstname == 'john' || value.lastname == 'john';
});

console.log($scope.filteredData);
 
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<body>

  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    {{filteredData}}
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

you can use like below.

```
$scope.filteredData = $filter('filter')(employees, function(value){
        return value.firstname == 'john' || value.lastname == 'john';
});
```