# How to use a model in a filter?

Tags: angularjs

I need to pass  bunch of variables to a filter, so I figured it'd be easier to pass the whole model, since it's just a reference anyway. So I tried to do this (this is a simplified version):

```
app.filter('applyLimit', function() {
  return function(files, m) {
    return files.map(function(v,i){
        v.analyze = i < m.limit
      return v
    })
  }
});

angular.module("app").component("h2jcomponent", {
    templateUrl: "html/View.html",
    controllerAs: "m",
    controller: ['$filter', H2J_Controller]
});

function H2J_Controller($filter) {
    var m = this
    m.limit = 1
    var files = [{name:'foo.java',analyze:true},{name:'bar.java',analyze:true}]
    $filter('applyLimit')(files,m)
}
```

However I'm getting the following error:

> `TypeError: Cannot read property 'limit' of undefined`

I'm assuming this is because I can't pass my entire model to a filter, but I'm not sure. Is this possible?

Comment: please try to replicate your problem on this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/0TYC56eNLSugPp8tDFeH?p=preview

Comment: yes i am also not getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'limit' of undefined

Comment: Near possible solution is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17813797/4593781)

Comment: @Andriy Sorry, didn't realize I didn't put `files` in as a param. https://plnkr.co/edit/el6yb3xRnkw4sku1kjEm?p=preview. That shows the issue, I've also edited my question. Also, because of this comment I was able to figure out the issue, I posted an answer, but if you want to post it, I'll delete mine and give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first filter's argument should be processed array (*files* in our case) and then after it any optional additional arguments (*limit* in our case).
This way, our filter may be used in HTML with directives like *ng-repeat* (`ng-repeat="file in vm.files | vm.applyLimit : vm"`) or just angular expression within curly braces like

```
<pre>{{ vm.files2 | applyLimit : vm | json }}</pre>
```

so I rewrote filter to:

```
app.filter('applyLimit', function() {
  return function(files, scope) {
    return files.map(function(v, i){
      v.analyze = i < scope.limit;
      return v;
    })
  }
});
```

updated plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/0TYC56eNLSugPp8tDFeH?p=preview

Comment: I want to pass in the model, not just limit (even though that's all it needs in this example). Why does it not work when I pass (files, m), and it does work when I pass (m,files)?

Comment: your plunker (https://plnkr.co/edit/el6yb3xRnkw4sku1kjEm?p=preview) works just fine, just add `m.files = angular.copy(files);` in your app.js (line 13 for example). It works when you pass (files, m). I updated my plunker and answer to receive model and not just limit

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why, but changing the order of the params fixed it:

```
app.filter('applyLimit', function() {
  return function(m, files) {           // <---- changed from (files,m) to (m,files)
    return files.map(function(v,i){
        v.analyze = i < m.limit
      return v
    })
  }
});

angular.module("app").component("h2jcomponent", {
    templateUrl: "html/View.html",
    controllerAs: "m",
    controller: ['$filter', H2J_Controller]
});

function H2J_Controller($filter) {
    var m = this
    m.limit = 1
    var files = [{name:'foo.java',analyze:true},{name:'bar.java',analyze:true}]
    $filter('applyLimit')(m,files)      // <---- also here
}
```