# limit the number of items shown in 2nd ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

i listed category from json data.i have listed number of sub category under category but i want to list only 3 sub category under category.if i click view more option i want to list corresponding sub category depends on category  in modal popup.

i have returned created div depends on parentid zero

```
  $scope.cat = categories.filter(function(category) {
    return category && category.parentid === 0
  });
```

i have updated my code in plunker.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Vh1NzYf0qjUkIygLUEJk?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

If you want a show more functionality refer the below Plunkr.

[`Plunkr`](http://plnkr.co/edit/VBN17osdHx4AAMzNnPSe?p=preview)

This will do the job. I have added a custom filter that takes the parent.Id as an argument and check the child's parent Id (which was done before by the ng-if). Then I use angular's `limit to: 3` filter to limit the results to only 3 items.

[`Plunkr`](http://plnkr.co/edit/VBN17osdHx4AAMzNnPSe?p=preview)

**Code:**

```
$scope.searchMe = function(statusId) {
    return function(user) { 
        return user.parentid === statusId;
    }
}
```

and the ng-repeat should look like

```
<div ng-repeat="item in cat">
    {{item.name}}
    <div ng-repeat="childItem in content | filter: searchMe(item.id) | limitTo: 3">
     <div style="margin-left: 20px;">
     {{childItem.name}}
     </div>
    </div>
    <a ng-click="open_modalpopup()">view more</a>
  </div>
```

References:

1. [Limit To](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo)
2. [passing arguements to angularJS filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753321/passing-arguments-to-angularjs-filters/)

Comment: You don't need custom filter

Comment: @MaximShoustin I got that just now, Thanks, great answer

Comment: @Naren Murali if i click view more i want to list all corresponding sub category depends on category

Comment: ng-click="limiter=limiter===3?1000:3" in this line what is the use of 1000

Comment: @user7098427 it limit to first 1000 values, but I have updated my answer to   allow max values to be shown.

Comment: when i use routing in angular if i click view more it goes to index page because u gave href="#"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152928/discussion-between-naren-murali-and-user7098427).

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by simlpe filter:

```
<div ng-repeat="childItem in content | filter: item.id | limitTo: 3">
```

<kbd>[Demo 1 plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NmDInd4BpRNJmoApUA5A?p=preview)</kbd>

It also will get rid of using `ng-if="childItem.parentid === item.id"`

Example:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in cat">
    {{item.name}}
    <div ng-repeat="childItem in content | filter: item.id | limitTo: 3">
     <div style="margin-left: 20px;" >
     {{childItem.name}}
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

---

If you want to handle `view more`, you can write:

```
<div ng-repeat="childItem in content | filter: item.id | limitTo: limit">
```

and:

```
$scope.limit = 3;

 $scope.viewMore = function(){
   $scope.limit = 100;
 }
```

<kbd>[Demo 2 plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1iEwcaJKyRnuxLVb7Ed2?p=preview)</kbd>

---

**[EDIT]**

if you want to update `view more` per sub-category, you need bind limit to your `data`:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="item in cat">
    {{item.name}}
    <div ng-repeat="childItem in content | filter: item.id | limitTo: item.limit">
     <div style="margin-left: 20px;" >
     {{childItem.name}}
     </div>         
    </div>
    <a href="" ng-click="viewMore(item)" 
               ng-if="item.limit == 3">view more</a>
  </div>
</body>
```

and:

```
$scope.viewMore = function(item){
   item.limit = 100;
}
```

<kbd>[Demo 3 plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/u1hs6J87Jukhwdi3sciT?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: if i click view more i want to list all corresponding sub category depends on category

Comment: if i click view more i want to list all corresponding sub category depends on category

Comment: @user7098427 You just need to bind `limit` to `item`

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE -**

As per your latest requirement -

> if i click view more i want to list all corresponding sub category
>   depends on category

I update the `plnkr` to show all categories in a popup once user clicked on `View More` button.

Updated Plnkr - http://plnkr.co/edit/OUvzqWdfZuQnZpbXWSRW?p=preview

---

As per your requirement I believe you need to *show/hide sub categories* on the basis of button click available under specific category.

I re arranged your data and rather than saving it into multiple objects, I am using a singular object `newcat` to store and manage the UI.

Working Plnkr -

http://plnkr.co/edit/F6MlkMWOJ2b7isRAM1u6?p=preview

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

var data = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'mobile',
    parentid: 0
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'samsung',
    parentid: 1
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'moto',
    parentid: 1
  }, {
    id: 4,
    name: 'redmi',
    parentid: 1
  }, {
    id: 5,
    name: 'honor',
    parentid: 1
  }, {
    id: 6,
    name: 'nokia',
    parentid: 1
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    name: 'tv',
    parentid: 0
  }, {
    id: 8,
    name: 'tv1',
    parentid: 7
  }, {
    id: 9,
    name: 'tv2',
    parentid: 7
  }, {
    id: 10,
    name: 'tv3',
    parentid: 7
  }, {
    id: 11,
    name: 'tv4',
    parentid: 7
  }, {
    id: 12,
    name: 'tv5',
    parentid: 7
  }];
  var categories = data;

  $scope.title = 'Show Hide Subcategories';

  $scope.cat = categories.filter(function(category) {
    return category && category.parentid === 0
  });

  $scope.newcat = angular.extend($scope.cat, {});

  angular.forEach($scope.cat, function(cat, key){
    var tmpIndex = 0;
    var tmpdata = categories.filter(function(category) {
      if(cat.id === category.parentid) {
        category.indexVal = tmpIndex;
        category.isShow = tmpIndex < 3 ? true : false;        
        tmpIndex++;
        return true;
      }
    })
    $scope.newcat[key]['subCat'] = tmpdata;
    $scope.newcat[key]['moreclicked'] = false;
  })

  $scope.showMore = function(index) {
    if(!$scope.newcat[index]['moreclicked']) {
      angular.forEach($scope.newcat[index].subCat, function(subcat, key) {
        subcat.isShow = true;
      })
      $scope.newcat[index]['moreclicked'] = true;
    }
    else {
      angular.forEach($scope.newcat[index].subCat, function(subcat, key) {
        if(key > 2)
          subcat.isShow = false;
      })
      $scope.newcat[index]['moreclicked'] = false;
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <h3 ng-bind="title"></h3>
  <div ng-repeat="cat in newcat">
    <b>{{cat.name}}</b>
    <div ng-repeat="subcat in cat.subCat">
     <div style="margin-left: 20px;" ng-if="subcat.isShow">
     {{subcat.name}}
     </div>
    </div>
    <button ng-click="showMore($index)" ng-bind="!cat.moreclicked ? 'View More': 'View Less'"></button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: if i click view more i want to list all corresponding sub category depends on category

Comment: @user7098427 Updated the plnkr