# How to select custom filter by expression?

Tags: angularjs

How to do this in angularjs ?

I have `field` value and `is_first_filter`(where `true` or `false`).
Where `is_first_filter` is `true` I want filtered `field` value by `firstCustomFilter`.

I can do this.

```
<p>field | is_first_filter ? firstCustomFilter : secondCustomFilter</p>
```

But it gives an error, so how can I select a filter by expression ?

Comment: Please describe what you want to accomblish and how what behavior you expect. To keep it short: Please describe "this" in your first sentence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to pass arguments to angular filter as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753321/passing-arguments-to-angularjs-filters/33604690#33604690)

Another option would be with tenary operator

```
{{ is_first_filter ? (field  | firstCustomFilter ) : (field | secondCustomFilter) }}
```